# JS regex - convert "any" plain text hostname/url/ip to a link

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been looking for a JS regexp that converts plain text url or hostnames to clickable links, but none of the script I found meet my requirements. Unfortunately, I suck at regex and are unable to modify the expression to work the way I want.

The plain text I wish to convert to links are:

1. Anything staring with http(s):, ftp(s):, mailto: or
   file:
2. domain.tld[:port][path][file][querystring]
3. any.sub.domain.tld[:port][path][file][querystring]
4. 0/255.0/255.0/255.0/255[:port][path][file][querystring]
5. locahost[:port][path][file][querystring]

[*] = optional.

Any help are highly appreciated!

Comment: Where do you want to find this plain text? A whole page or ...

Comment: The idea is basically to save a "location", this location could be a place, like "New York", but in most cases a url or hostname. So the whole plain text will be a link, or no link at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with false positives, such as `something.notavalidtld` or `999.999.999.999` getting matched, what you are looking for is probably something like this. (Otherwise, it gets [more messy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).)

Start matching at the beginning of the string.

```
^(
```

Match anything starting with http/https/ftp/...

```
((https?|ftps?|mailto|file):.*?)
```

**OR** match the all of the below.

```
|
```

Optionally match http/https/ftp/... followed by `:` and at least one `/`.

```
((https?|ftps?|mailto|file):/+)?
```

Match an IP address...

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

...or a domain (with optional username/password, which also matches email addresses)...

```
|([\w\d.:_%+-]+@)?([\w\d-]+\.)+[\w\d]{2,}
```

... or `localhost`.

```
|localhost)
```

Optionally followed by a port number.

```
(:\d+)?
```

Optionally followed by any path/query string.

```
(/.*)?
```

Ensuring the string ends here.

```
)$
```

All the above parts should be joined together without any whitespace in between.

I haven't tested it extensively, so I might have missed something. But at least you have a starting point.